# Make Panel scrollable

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I am working on a simple Windows Forms application which consists of a `Panel` where I draw graphics with `Graphic`. Let's say, my panel is now of size **300x300** but the content inside is **500x500**. Obviously, I need to add scrollbars to the `Panel`.

My code so far:

```
public CircuitControl()
{
    // Initialize empty list of circuit objects
    CircuitObjects = new List<CircuitObject>();

    drawingAreaPanel.AutoScroll = true;
    drawingAreaPanel.VerticalScroll.Enabled = true;
    drawingAreaPanel.VerticalScroll.Visible = true;
    drawingAreaPanel.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = true;

    drawingAreaPanel.MaximumSize = new Size(300, 300);
    drawingAreaPanel.Size = new Size(600, 600);
}
```

But none of these codes create actually a scroll bar. My question is: Where and how do I set the size of the `Panel` where I actually drew? I think this is the part which is missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scrollbars won't show up until there's actually something in the `Panel` that you can't see all of.

Try placing a larger control, such as a `PictureBox`, inside the `Panel`, and setting the `PictureBox`'s initial size as larger than the `Panel`.

Comment: Ok. This works and solves the first part of my problem. But now I already draw in the `Panel` outside the visible area and this doesn't create any scrollbars. Is there a way to draw and create scrollbars by drawing? Or do I need to create actual `Control`?

Comment: The simplest way is probably just to make a `Panel` within a `Panel`, and draw on the inner one.

Comment: You can also use a graphics context to draw to a `Bitmap` object, and use a `PictureBox` instead of a `Panel`. `PictureBox`es will scroll automatically if you give them an image too big to show.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it lead me to the right way. Panel inside Panel with a dynamically calculated size is the solution. This saves me a lot of time converting all drawn elements to `Control`s.

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
drawingAreaPanel.AutoScroll = true;
```

And it will be done automatically.

€dit: Don't forget to set the anchors in order to get the scrollbars.

Comment: As you can see in my source code, this is already there. The anchors are set to Left, Top. Also with 4 anchors it doesn't work.

Comment: If you want a vertical scrollbar you have to set the anchors to the top as far as I know. Besides that, there has to be content in the panel, because the scrollbars won't appear if there is nothing to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

A clean and simple approach is to set `AutoScrollMinSize`. This shows the scrollbars (or just one if you leave the other value at 0).
Now drawing through the graphics object will *not* be scrolled automatically.
This can be easily achieved with a transformation matrix, which is set before painting and translates the drawing by the scroll offset.
A pretty example: <sup>(this flickers of course without further optimizations)</sup>

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(Form frm = new Form())
    {
        Panel pnl = new Panel();
        pnl.Paint += delegate (Object snd, PaintEventArgs e2)  {
            Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
            mtx.Translate(pnl.AutoScrollPosition.X, pnl.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
            e2.Graphics.Transform = mtx;
            e2.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black);
            for(int i=0; i <= 125; i++)
                for(int j=0; j <= 125; j++)
                    using(Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255-i*2, j*2, (i*j) % 255)))
                        e2.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, new Rectangle(5+j*20, 5+i*20, 20, 20));
        };
        pnl.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(126*20+10, 126*20+10);
        pnl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        frm.Controls.Add(pnl);
        frm.Padding = new Padding(25);
        frm.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
```